# Chromium developer tools -- javascript debugger and editing

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I noticed that the Chrome Javascript debugger, in `Chromium 6.0.467.0 (52418) Ubuntu 10.04`, has the ability to /edit/ the Javascript, by double clicking the line in the Javascript viewing pane. How do I get my edits to hold? The second I lose focus they revert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a bug; in Chrome 5 it is just static.